# Unable to pass parameter to apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

```
@AuraEnabled  
public static List<RecordType> getDesc(string sObjectParam) {
    recTypes = new list<RecordType>();
for(RecordType rtd : [Select Name, Description FROM RecordType
    where SobjectType =: sObjectParam and isActive = true]) {
        recTypes.add(rtd);
    }

return recTypes;
}
```

and the component function

```
 getDescriptions: function(component) {

    var action = component.get("c.getDesc");
       action.setParam(
           "sObjectParam", Sales_Toolkit__c
       );
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var ListOfDescriptions = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.lstOfDesc", ListOfDescriptions);     

        /* var recordDescList = [];
        //Creating recordDescList from retrieved list
        for(var key in ListOfDescriptions){
            recordDescList.push(ListOfDescriptions[key]);
             component.set("v.lstOfDesc", recordDescList);

        }*/
    });
   $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Prior i had where

```
SobjectType = 'Sales_Toolkit__c'
```

it was hardcoded but i wanted to reuse the apex handler for other components (IE to get a list of the description of records and iterate them over a components html) So i figured i'd just pass a parameter and hardcode the sObject....but it's not reading it as it should. So everything worked until i added the parameter.

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Sales_Toolkit__c is not defined]
>   Callback failed: apex://recordType/ACTION$fetchRecordTypeValues

Answer (score 3):

You are missing quotes around your value you try to pass in.

**What you have:**

```
action.setParam(
    "sObjectParam", Sales_Toolkit__c
//  ^ quotes     ^  ^ no quotes    ^
);
```

**Corrected:**

```
action.setParam(
    "sObjectParam", "Sales_Toolkit__c"
//  ^ quotes     ^  ^ quotes         ^
);
```

Also I typically use `setParams instead, which would look like:

```
action.setParams({
    "sObjectParam": "Sales_Toolkit__c"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to pass parameters to the aura methods is by using `action.setParams()`, by directly referencing the argument name (without quotes) that you have in your apex method and passing the argument value (within quotes) separated by a `:`.

In your case this should be written as:

```
action.setParams({sObjectParam: "Sales_Toolkit__c"});
```

Refer to the docs [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) for details on this.

> Use `action.setParams()` to set data to be passed to the server-side controller.

Comment: It's `action.setParams({ sObjectParam: "Sales_Toolkit__c" })` (note the object notation required here).

Comment: Oh yeah right. Typical copy paste issue :)

Comment: The documentation link no longer works, FYI

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to amend to this.

```
action.setParam( "sObjectParam": "Sales_Toolkit__c");
```

If you are getting this from the current object and your not in a community you could implement force:hasSObjectName

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasSObjectName/documentation

Then add this attribute:

Then your action becomes

action.setParam("sObjectParam":component.get("v.sObjectName"));

Comment: It's `,`, not `:`, fyi.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the "setParams" call needs to be changed. However, it needs a Javascript Object to be passed in as an argument, as follows:

```
action.setParams({"sObjectParam":"Sales_Toolkit__c"});
```

Comment: There's a method called `setParam`, with the signature `(parameter, value)`, like if you were specifying a map's key. So they are also correct in their examples.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not technically a "JSON object" (JSON being an over-the-wire protocol that is meant to be human-readable). It's a Javascript Object, which is what JSON is based on (the JavaScript Object Notation). This object will be converted to a JSON string before being sent to the server, but the developer shouldn't normally be directly interacting with JSON strings.

Comment: Agreed with @sfdcfox. Edited answer, accordingly. Renato, I couldn't find 'setParam' method in the documentation. Would appreciate it if you could link that here. Thanks!